# Unable to autowire the Processor after adding User-defined message converters

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

On Finchley.SR2, here is the code

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
@RestController
public class Application {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    @Autowired
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter testConverter;

    @Bean
    @StreamMessageConverter
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter createTestConverter(){
        return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I start up, I got

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

But if I take out @StreamMessageConverter, the Processor can be autowired successfully.

What should I do to keep my customized message converter and autowired Processor at the same time? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot going on there, so lets try to parse it put. . .

First question, why do you need to autowire the following?

```
@Autowired
private Processor processor;
```

You, generally don't need to interact with `Processor` directly since it is used bt the framework to provide a delegation/connectivity model between remote destinations exposed by the binders and your message handlers
Further more, your actual issue is related to a lifecycle which may be a minor yet harmless bug on our end and probably relates to configuring and autowiring Processor in the same configuration class.

Second:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @SpringBootApplication
```

You only need one

```
 @SpringBootApplication
```

Third:

Why do you need to configure `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`? Content type conversion is a transparent feature of he framework and while we do provide an ability to configure custom message converters, the one you are configuring is already configured by the framework and in fact is the first in the stack of seven pre-configured message converters

The final question:

What is it that your are trying to do? Can you explain your use case?

Comment: Also, what are you doing with `@RestController` there?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
I am replacing the default MessageConverter with our own, because we want to add more metadata to our messages. That is why this snippet is copy pasted from existing code and then simplified.

I am using MappingJackson2MessageConverter just to reproduce behaviour - I started with our own customized message converter

Comment: That only answers one question, but as I said, there is a lot going on and I can't make sense of it, so I gave you the pointers, hopefully that helps. 
Another thing you can do is to create a sample (bare minimum) project that reproduces the issue and push it to Github or any other repo so we can take a look

Comment: You are so right! The problem is gone once I put my processor in a separate Component, and EnableBinding in a separate Configuration. Thanks a lot for your pointers!